# how to place thumbnails of a playlist just using playlistID in a recyclerview in android using youtube android player api?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-youtube-api

I am trying to make a recyclerview with youtube thumbnails of a youtube playlist just by using its playlistId. Each thumbnail of the playlist should be in each row of that recyclerview and when the user clicks on particular thumbnail's above button it will open that particular video in other activity inside YoutubePlayerView.
Here is my code:

VideoListAdapter.java

```
public class VideoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.VideoListViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private int numberOfVideosInPlaylist = 10;
    private String videoId;
    public VideoListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public String getVideoId() {
        return videoId;
    }
    public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
        this.videoId = videoId;
    }
    @Override
    public VideoListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tile_view, parent, false);
        VideoListViewHolder holder = new VideoListViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, PlayVideoActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("VideoId", getVideoId());
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return numberOfVideosInPlaylist;
    }
    class VideoListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
        private ImageView playButton;
        public VideoListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            youTubeThumbnailView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tile);
            playButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
            youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(DeveloperKeyAndPlayListId.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setPlaylist(DeveloperKeyAndPlayListId.PLAYLIST_ID);
                    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener onThumbnailLoadedListener = new ThumbnailListener(youTubeThumbnailLoader);
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
                }
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to load thumbnail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private final class ThumbnailListener implements
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {
        private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
        public ThumbnailListener() {
            super();
        }
        public ThumbnailListener(YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
            this();
            this.youTubeThumbnailLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader;
        }
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
            if (youTubeThumbnailLoader.hasNext()) {
                youTubeThumbnailLoader.next();
            }
            setVideoId(s);
        }
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to load thumbnail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

PlayVideoActivity.java

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);
        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                String videoId = bundle.getString("VideoId");
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
            }
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(PlayVideoActivity.this, "Unable to play video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(DeveloperKeyAndPlayListId.DEVELOPER_KEY, onInitializedListener);
    }
}
```

This is what i want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWLNl.png)

onclick of that play button:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo2XI.png)

Here in my code, i hardcode the number of videos in the playlist. If you can get it from playlistId that will be really helpful.